# Apache's Rewrite Condition not file (!-f) behaviour

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have basic htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ rewrite.php?data=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It works as expected for the most part. What doesn't work as I would like it to is this:

I have this link that doesn't rewrite as per the rule:

http://domain.com/movies.php

But also these url's are not rewritten either:

http://domain.com/movies
http://domain.com/movies/
http://domain.com/movies/fdgdgdgdg

Is this normal behaviour? How can I fix this so that the only working url would end with  movies.php

Comment: That's curious. Can you give an example of a URL for which the rewrite _does_ work? Also, what do you get for the URLs where it doesn't work? A 404 error?

Comment: According to your ruleset, this: `http://domain.com/movies/fdgdgdgdg` is mapped silently as this: `http://domain.com/rewrite.php?data=/movies/fdgdgdgdg`, for example. ¿Are you sure that's what you want? If not, please give some examples of the incoming and the mapped URLs you want, starting with the example of the mapped URL for `http://domain.com/movies.php`.

Comment: The below answer solved my issue thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a multiviews problem. Disable multiviews with

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Comment: That was it! Can you elaborate a bit about this option? And why would this option be enabled by default on linux shared hosting but not synology nas? Seems odd that it would be enabled by default anywhere...

Comment: Don't know why it is enabled by default by apache (not just you host). It's the first thing I disable, when working with mod_rewrite. What MultiViews does is, when the file can't be found, see if there is a file that "comes close". So in your case with the request for `/movies`, MultiViews sees that there is a file with the basename the same as the request, so it will serve `/movies.php`. This is the short version of how Content Negotiation works. More info at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html