# Htaccess "not file" (!-f) mistakenly matching file name

Tags: .htaccess, file

My *htaccess* file is mistakenly matching the following url as a file.

```
www.mysite.com/robots/robot-name/1
```

In my root directory, like any other site, I have a **robots.txt** file that is messing the *htaccess* up.

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /htaccess
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^(.*) [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)(/?)(.*) index.php?page=$1&vars=$3 [NC,QSA,L]
```

How can force the **%{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f** to match a complete file name?]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean, "complete filename". `-f` works at the filesystem level. unless you really have a directory `robots`, subdirectory `robot-name`, with a file name `1` in there, there's nothing for -f to match against.

Comment: @MarcB I KNOW RIGHT?!?! But for some CRAZY reason it is matching. If I remove or rename the "robots.txt" It'll work. Try it for yourself.

Comment: That isn't a URL. A URL starts with a scheme which is followed by a colon, like "http:".

Comment: @AndrewMorton Oh please! That´s not the issue! X(

Comment: What's in the "robots.txt" file?

Comment: check what value is in `%{SCRIPT_FILENAME}` in the first place. since you're doing a `not` test, an empty script_fielname would technically NOT be a file, triggering the rule.

Comment: Turn off multiviews. Put this at the very top of your htaccess and see if it helps. `Options -MultiViews`

Comment: @AndrewMorton It does't mater the name, contents, nor the extension of the file, **mysite.com/index/something/** will also match as a file because I have my **index.php**

Comment: @UriasBT Is this a duplicate of [Apache's Rewrite Condition not file (!-f) behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14131216/1115360)?

Comment: @PanamaJack IT WORKS!!!!!! That was exactly the issue. Thank you soo much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED! Thanks to **PanamaJack** for the help. I just disabled **MultiViews** and problem solved. Final *htaccess* bellow:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /htaccess
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^(.*) [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)(/?)(.*) index.php?page=$1&vars=$3 [NC,QSA,L]
```